# How to select from relationship based on the height value of field postgres?

Tags: postgresql

i have three tables vehicles and trips and componentValues they are related to each other by

```
vehicles -> trips -> componentValues 

vehicles Table : id, ...

trips Table: id, vehicle_id, ...

componentValues Table: id, trip_id, damage, ...
```

and i'm trying to get all the trips with the highest damage component form the componentValues table like this

```
SELECT *
 FROM (select * from trips WHERE "trips"."vehicle_id" = '7') as t
 LEFT JOIN (
    select * from "component_values"
    where trip_id = '85'
    order by damage
    desc nulls last limit 1
) as h on t.id = h.trip_id
```

how can i change the line `where trip_id = '85'` to be dynamic or is their another way to do this and many thanks in advance.

expected result:

[image]

**UPDATE**

i have did some query that get what i want but how can i improve it by not using sub queries in the select statement

```
select * ,
(select damage from "component_values" where trip_id = trips.id order by damage desc nulls last limit 1) as h_damage,
(select damage from "component_values" where trip_id = trips.id order by damage asc nulls first limit 1) as l_damage,
(select component_types.name from "component_values" left join component_types on component_values.component_type_id = component_types.id where trip_id = trips.id  order by damage desc nulls last limit 1) as hc_damage,
(select component_types.name from "component_values" left join component_types on component_values.component_type_id = component_types.id where trip_id = trips.id  order by damage asc nulls first limit 1) as lc_damage
from trips 
WHERE trips."vehicle_id" = '7'
```

Comment: You have tagged with MySQL/Laravel as well as Postgres.  Which database are you actually using here?

Comment: i assume because of the double quotes indentifiers you are using PostgreSQL.. Unless you run MySQL with a enabled sql_mode ANSI_QUOTES..  Also MySQL does not support `nulls last` on `order by ... `

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "all the trips"... It would be useful to have some sample data and expected output!

Comment: Question is indeed unclear without example data and without expected results.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ... But i have a feeling you try the select the largest 1 per group..

Comment: i'm using postgres

Comment: 1. Please add some sample data. Only the result is not very useful if we cannot see the source. 2. Please do NOT add images, please add the data as text or fiddle. As an image it is not possible for us to copy the data for testing purposes. 3. Please minimize the sample.

Comment: @S-Man i added new query to the question hope that will help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (t.id) t.*, dv.damage
from trips t join
     component_values cv
     on cv.trip_id = t.id
where t.vehicle_id = 7  -- not sure if this is needed
order by t.id, cv.damage desc nulls last;
```

`distinct on` is usually the most efficient method in Postgres.  You can also do this with window functions:

```
select distinct on (t.id) t.*, cv.damage
from trips t join
     (select cv.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cv.trip_id, cv.damage desc nulls last) as seqnum
      from component_values cv
     ) cv
     on cv.trip_id = t.id and cv.seqnum = 1
where t.vehicle_id = 7;  -- not sure if this is needed
```

Comment: it's returning the damage as null for all the rows

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff  your query is working right with some modification instead of  `order by t.id, cv.damage desc` i change it to `order by  t.id desc , cv.damage desc nulls last` but is their another way to do this without using `distinct on` because i will need to convert this query to laravel eloquent query

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a lateral join.

```
SELECT *
 FROM (select * from trips WHERE "trips"."vehicle_id" = '7') as t
 LEFT JOIN lateral (
    select * from "component_values"
    where trip_id = t.id
    order by damage
    desc nulls last limit 1
) as h on true
```

Although I don't think there is a reason for the first subquery, so:

```
SELECT *
 FROM trips
 LEFT JOIN lateral (
    select * from "component_values"
    where trip_id = trips.id
    order by damage
    desc nulls last limit 1
) as h on true
WHERE "trips"."vehicle_id" = '7'
```